# How to change a text in PHP?

Tags: php, string, text

I'm trying to change the name of three attributes using a string in PHP, but I'm stuck.
Could you help me?

This is the code that I had:

```
function color () {
    switch ($color) {
    case "red":
        echo "purple";
        break;
    case "yellow":
        echo "yellow brown";
        break;
    case "brown":
        echo "chocolate";
        break;
    }
}
```

Also, I was trying using the same with a string but I'm not sure if it's okey:

```
<?php

$color = "'red', 'yellow', 'brown', 'pizza', 'moustard', 'mango', 'lemon'"; 

$searchColor = array ('red','yellow', 'brown');

$replacements = array ( 'purple', 'yellow brown','chocolate');

echo str_replace( $searchColor, $replacements, $color );

?>
```

Comment: RE: Your function! Please review [Function Scope](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) in the PHP Manual

Comment: ___but I'm not sure if it's okey___ Does it work?

Comment: Nope :( I was trying with the string to find for the attribute and replace with the correct one.

Comment: Maybe this 

`<?php
$a = 'red';
$b = 'yellow';
$c = 'brown';

function color()
{
    global $a, $b, $c;

    $a = 'purple';
    $b = 'yellow brown';
    $c = 'chocolate';
} 

Sum();
echo $a; $b; $c;
?>`

Comment: What is your question? The code does what it is told to, it echos:
'purple', 'yellow chocolate', 'chocolate', 'pizza', 'moustard', 'mango', 'lemon'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

However this would work, because this also includes the single quotes in the checking and replacing, so the `yellow` does not get processed twice

```
$searchColor = array ("'red'", "'brown'", "'yellow'");
$replacements = array ( "'purple'", "'chocolate'", "'yellow brown'");
echo str_replace( $searchColor, $replacements, $color);
```

RESULT

```
'purple', 'yellow brown', 'chocolate', 'pizza', 'moustard', 'mango', 'lemon'
```